# Black screen at boot with nvidia / Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

Last week, after updating my system (Ubuntu 16.10) on reboot I got a black screen. No blinking cursor, just all black. Fortunately, I can access to tty console.

So after some research from my phone, it seems to be a problem between the last version of Ubuntu and my nvidia drivers (375 I think, but not sure).
According to multiple forums, I try to reinstall my driver (`apt-get purge nvidia-*`, reboot then `apt-get install nvidia-375` and reboot again) : nothing change, still a black screen.

I also tried to remove my Xorg.conf, but still the same. So I completely removed nvidia drivers, installed nouveau, and when I reboot, I finally got my usual login screen (except it's poor quality, probably caused by a bad config with nouveau).

After some other research, it seems that old versions of nvidia drivers didn't work (black screen, as always).
So, if someone can help me to fix that. I'm ready to do a lot of tests with no-ending reboot if necessary.

Some additional information:

- System : Ubuntu 16.10, Linux : 4.8.0-37-generic
- Desktop environment : KDE (last version)
- Graphics card : Nvidia GeForce GTX 460

I also, with nvidia-375 and a black screen, extract some informations from system / sddm logs :

```
mars 21 20:35:52 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Initializing...
mars 21 20:35:52 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Starting...
mars 21 20:35:52 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Adding new display on vt 7 ...
mars 21 20:35:52 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Display server starting...
mars 21 20:35:52 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{a531063c-31f6-4d0c-b6ba-0c01b2c60b28} -background none -noreset -displayfd 18 vt7
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Display server started.
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Socket server starting...
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Socket server started.
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Greeter starting...
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{a531063c-31f6-4d0c-b6ba-0c01b2c60b28}"
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm-helper[1456]: [PAM] Starting...
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm-helper[1456]: [PAM] Authenticating...
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux sddm-helper[1456]: [PAM] returning.
mars 21 20:35:55 fixe-linux systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of sddm.
mars 21 20:35:56 fixe-linux systemd-logind[1039]: New session 1 of user sddm.
mars 21 20:35:56 fixe-linux systemd[1]: Started Session 1 of user sddm.
mars 21 20:35:56 fixe-linux systemd[1459]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user sddm by (uid=0)
mars 21 20:35:56 fixe-linux sddm-helper[1456]: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm by (uid=0)
mars 21 20:35:56 fixe-linux sddm-helper[1456]: pam_systemd(sddm-greeter:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
mars 21 20:35:56 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Greeter session started successfully
mars 21 20:35:57 fixe-linux sddm-greeter[1462]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
mars 21 20:35:57 fixe-linux sddm-greeter[1462]: Connected to the daemon.
mars 21 20:35:57 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Message received from greeter: Connect
mars 21 20:35:59 fixe-linux sddm-greeter[1462]: Adding view for "default" QRect(0,0 1280x800)
mars 21 20:35:59 fixe-linux sddm-greeter[1462]: Message received from daemon: Capabilities
mars 21 20:35:59 fixe-linux sddm-greeter[1462]: Message received from daemon: HostName
mars 21 20:35:59 fixe-linux sddm-greeter[1462]: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
mars 21 20:35:59 fixe-linux sddm-greeter[1462]: Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0)
mars 21 20:36:00 fixe-linux sddm-helper[1456]: [PAM] Ended.
mars 21 20:36:00 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 6
mars 21 20:36:00 fixe-linux sddm[1178]: Greeter stopped.
```

My last try was to install SLime launcher and boot with nivdia drivers. It works (I got a login screen), but after authentication, I got an error message that globally said `Can not use/find OpenGL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: More specifically, possible duplicate of [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](/q/41681/175814). The relevant answer to Elder Geeks's linked question suggests this link for your case.

Comment: It's fix a problem : no black screen anymore. But still with nouveau and it's bad graphical quality. Only one screen (on two) detected, and I can't change resolution.